# Change SMS App Default on Android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms, default

I would change default sms app on Android 4.4.2

I use this code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
sendIntent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

How can i solve this? And how can i ask to change default sms app with my app?

My Receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="receiver.SMSHandlerReceiver"
     android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
      <intent-filter>      
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is it necessary to change the default SMS app from your application? The default app is a user choice, and so imo, forcing another option can be construed as malicious.

Comment: I would ask to change the default app..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that if you want your app to appear in default sms app settings, you must first make it eligible, or else you can not set your app as default sms app. I had the same problem so I did those simple steps and then I could chose my app as default, in settings and in my code, which I could not before.

So :

- You must Have an Activity including an intent filter with an ACTION_SENDTO ("android.intent.action.SENDTO" ) and with schemas sms, smsto, mms, and mmsto. Do it in your manifest file. What I did was creating an empty activity that I will not use, with those parameters.
- Do the same, by creating an empty Service  including an intent filter with ACTION_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE ("android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE") and with schemas, sms, smsto, mms, and mmsto. This service must also require the SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE permission. You must add all required permissions in your manifest.
- Create an empty BroadcastReceiver  including an intent filter with WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION ("android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER") with the MIME type application/vnd.wap.mms-message. The broadcast receiver must also require the BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH permission. You must add all required permissions in your manifest.
- Create an empty BroadcastReceiver including an intent filter with SMS_DELIVER_ACTION ("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"). The broadcast receiver must also require the BROADCAST_SMS permission. You must add all required permissions in your manifest.

It important to set all these parameters without missing one. Once you made all these steps, your app will be eligible and you can then set it as default sms app, leaving those created classes empty, and sticking with you old way of doing things. The goal is simply set your app as default, so it will be fully fonctionnal like it was before, without code modification.

Comment: Ulan yine ne varsa şu Türklerde var he :D Bende aranıyodum, bende servis yok, nasıl tanımlicam diye :)

Comment: Aynen, mühendis ruhu var bizde napalim =D kafa çalisiyor kullanmak gerek.

Comment: MMS işlemleri hakkında bilgin var mı? Birkaç örnek proje buldum ama sade bir kod dizimi yok.. Senin bildiğin MMS gönderme veya alma dökümanları var mı?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2222703 bu site de açiklamalar var, stackoverflow da da bulabilirsin, ben simdilik mms lerle ugrasmiyorum.

Comment: Bu linke bende denk gelmiştim ama bende henüz sms ile uğraştığım için çok uğraşmak istemedim :) SmsManager.sendMultipartSmsMessage() gibi kolay bi kod arıyordum :) Bu arada E-Mail adresini kullanıyor musun? Yani oradan ulaşabilir miyim sana?

Comment: any example code? i did all the following but still no results :(

Comment: you are doing something wrong or something is missing. you must follow all these steps or else it does not work. Also when you set shemes, you must separate them by creating new data in intent filter for each sheme. Maybe you created one data in your intent filter for all sms, mms, smsto,mmsto shemes, instead of creating 4 data and setting only one sheme in each of it.

Comment: Did you change your default.properties file to target sdk 19? project.properties must also target sdk 19, also in your manifest you can target sdk 11 for example, for best compatibility while fully supporting kitkat. Maybe you are just not using kitkat library, right after gen folder, it must be Android 4.4 or > . when you are done with these steps, do Project/Clean, then right click on your project/Android tools/Fix Porject Properties.

Comment: Great instructions!! Followed them and I've got my app showing the dialog and setting itself as default. New guys implementing this feature; please consider having a look at this link: http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/03/11/bitesize-android-kitkat-week-4-replacing-the-default-sms-app

Comment: tnx I do the steps above and I make my app as default sms app, but there is a problem, as my app turned to default sms app user can not send even a simple sms with mobile default messaging app, the send new button is disabled!!!!!  what should I do? I want keep my app as default sms app but enable user to send sms via default android messaging app

Comment: This will help you  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Answer (score 5):

> I would change default sms app on Android 4.4.2

You cannot change the default SMS app. You can, however, ask the user to change the default SMS app, using `Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT`. This is covered in [the official blog post on the SMS changes in Android 4.4](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

Comment: @user3253955: What is your problem? The code seems fine. Note, though, that there may not be such an activity, particularly on devices that do not have telephony capability.

Comment: The phone has telephony capability. The problem is that this code doesn't show the request to change. I must add any permission or implement other? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3253955: I am not aware of any required permission to be able to use this. If you are crashing, look at the Java stack trace. If the stack trace has a `SecurityException`, it should inform you of any missing permission. If the stack trace is `ActivityNotFoundException`, then, for whatever reason, your device manufacturer (or ROM mod creator) did not offer this capability. If you are not crashing, then, for whatever reason, your device manufacturer (or ROM mod creator) did something really strange. :-)

Comment: I'm not crashing and the stack trace does not report anything :( I try this code both on my phone and on the eclipse emulator. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3253955: Does your app implement all the things listed in the first part of that blog post, to be a fully-qualified SMS client? In particular, I am thinking of the all of the manifest entries. I do not know exactly how Android is deciding what is or is not an SMS client for the purposes of these change-the-default dialogs. It may be that your app is incomplete and therefore does not qualify at present.

Comment: @user3253955: Probably that is insufficient. The blog post has: "In order for your app to appear in the system settings as an eligible default SMS app, your manifest file must declare some specific capabilities. So you must update your app to do the following things:", which is followed by four bullets. Your code, at best, implements one of those four. I would imagine, based on the phrasing of that post, that you need to support *all* of those capabilities, not just a subset.

Comment: I've now implemented all thing that are descripted in that manifest, but my app in not eligible default sms app. Why?

Comment: @user3253955: No clue, sorry.

Comment: Did you change your default.properties file to target sdk 19? project.properties must also target sdk 19, also in your manifest you can target sdk 11 for example, for best compatibility while fully supporting kitkat. Maybe you are just not using kitkat library, right after gen folder, it must be Android 4.4 or >

Comment: @CommonsWare I am following this in my live app and it's working fine except in one plus devices. I am getting null in Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).

Comment: @SagarMaiyad: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide a [mcve] showing what you are doing. This question and answer are nearly 7 years old at this point.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sure, should I tag you in that? In case you can help me with that.

Comment: @CommonsWare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64746216/change-default-sms-app-issue-in-one-plus-devices